# ValueError when attempting to fit a GaussianNB classifier with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I was trying to fit a dataset that I had compiled for a project with a Gaussian NB. My goal is to see that given a set of features whether I would be able to predict a GINI Index (typically between 0 to 1) for a county and at what accuracy. I have visualized the dataset and it can be viewed on my Tableau Public site here - https://public.tableau.com/profile/sandeep.mohan#!/vizhome/RisingIncomeInequalityintheUSsince2010/Story1 . It also gives some context of the data itself.

Here is my code so far. As you can see I have removed all the categorical and non numeric (an I am down to ints and one float - the GINI Index itself). I then try to fit it but it returns a value error. So I tried to go back and explicitly indicate the target was a float.

What am I doing wrong? Code is below. Thanks in advance for reviewing!!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv("consdf_fin.csv")
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22544 entries, 0 to 22543
Data columns (total 38 columns):
FIPS                       22544 non-null int64
County_Name                22544 non-null object
African_American_Male      22544 non-null int64
African_American_Female    22544 non-null int64
Native_Male                22544 non-null int64
Native_Female              22544 non-null int64
Asian_Male                 22544 non-null int64
Asian_Female               22544 non-null int64
Hispanic_Male              22544 non-null int64
Hispanic_Female            22544 non-null int64
summary_est                22544 non-null float64
year                       22544 non-null int64
Other_Male                 22544 non-null int64
Other_Female               22544 non-null int64
White_Male                 22544 non-null int64
White_Female               22544 non-null int64
GINI_Index                 22544 non-null float64
GINI_Low                   22544 non-null float64
GINI_High                  22544 non-null float64
Total_Occupied_Housing     22544 non-null int64
Occupied_Housing_Owner     22544 non-null int64
Occupied_Housing_Renter    22544 non-null int64
Black_MI                   22544 non-null int64
Asian_MI                   22544 non-null int64
White_MI                   22544 non-null int64
Hispanic_MI                22544 non-null int64
County_Median_Income       22544 non-null int64
Other_MI                   22544 non-null int64
Total                      22544 non-null int64
Employed_BS_or_Less        22544 non-null int64
Employed_BS_or_More        22544 non-null int64
Unemployed_BS_or_Less      22544 non-null int64
Unemployed_BS_or_More      22544 non-null int64
Total_Educ_Emp             22544 non-null int64
In_Poverty_Male            22544 non-null int64
In_Poverty_Female          22544 non-null int64
pct_in_poverty             22544 non-null float64
Total_Poverty              22544 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(32), object(1)
memory usage: 6.5+ MB

df.drop(columns=['County_Name','summary_est', 'GINI_Low', 'GINI_High', 'pct_in_poverty'],inplace=True)

collist = df.columns.tolist()
print(collist)
len(collist)

df= df[['FIPS', 'African_American_Male', 'African_American_Female', 'Native_Male', 
        'Native_Female', 'Asian_Male', 'Asian_Female', 'Hispanic_Male', 'Hispanic_Female', 
        'year', 'Other_Male', 'Other_Female', 'White_Male', 'White_Female', 
        'Total_Occupied_Housing', 'Occupied_Housing_Owner', 'Occupied_Housing_Renter', 
        'Black_MI', 'Asian_MI', 'White_MI', 'Hispanic_MI', 'County_Median_Income', 'Other_MI', 'Total', 
        'Employed_BS_or_Less', 'Employed_BS_or_More', 'Unemployed_BS_or_Less', 'Unemployed_BS_or_More', 
        'Total_Educ_Emp', 'In_Poverty_Male', 'In_Poverty_Female', 'Total_Poverty','GINI_Index']]


features = df.values[:,0:31]
target = df.values[:,32]
features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 10)

target_train = target_train.astype('float')
target_test = target_test.astype('float')

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, target_train)
target_pred = clf.predict(features_test)
accuracy_score(target_test, target_pred)



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-a3d0dedcdf18> in <module>()
      1 clf = GaussianNB()
----> 2 clf.fit(features_train, target_train)
      3 target_pred = clf.predict(features_test)
      4 accuracy_score(target_test, target_pred)

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([0.2001, 0.207 , 0.304 , ..., 0.626 , 0.645 , 0.6519]),)
```

Comment: Try adding the line `target_train=target_train.astype('int')`

Comment: @Shruti V - So in order to make that column an int, I needed to go back to the original dataframe and multiply it by 100 and round and make it an int (the value is supposed to be between 0-1). Still tried it out and the code works as is and returns a pitiable 0.02 accuracy score. **So the issue seems to be how to I get the train/test target and features to handle floats.** The Gaussian NB classifier is probably not the best then for predicting given the features....